# How to create and address merged cells in OpenXml without explicit cell references?

Tags: c#, openxml

I've Googled and found lots of code samples of how to create merged cells using OpenXml.  But all of them assume that you already know the literal cell references of the cells you want to merge.

In my particular case, I am generating a spreadsheet from report data, with columns and rows to be determined by the data I want to display.  And in several places I need to merge a variable number of cells, depending on how many data values share a group value.

Please could someone provide code (or references thereto) that demonstrate how to generate a spreadsheet with horizontal and vertical cell merges, without knowing what the explicit cell references of the merged cells are?

Comment: from where do you get the info that the operation is possible without the cell references of the merged cells ?

Comment: @ElYusubov - Are you telling me it's *not* possible?  Seriously?  So how would you do what I want to do?

Comment: what i am telling is that how you will merge cells without cell references?

Comment: Since you are generating your own spreadsheet you should be able to determine the cell references.

Comment: @ElYusubov I was hoping to be able to do stuff sequentially, like `row.Append(mergedCells)` or something like that.  You don't have to know the cell references to append cells.

Comment: @JonPeterson - true, I could keep a running counter of rows and columns.  I was hoping not to have to do that, though.  It's a bit like doing `for (var n = 0; n<array.Count; n++)` instead of `foreach (var obj in array)`.  Just feels like wasted cycles...